# Must the composition of a function with a surjective function be surjective?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I'm looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function), and I don't see an example like this:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\zeta_1 & \xrightarrow{f} \omega_1 & \xrightarrow{g} \epsilon_1 \\
\zeta_2 & \rightarrow \omega_2 & \rightarrow \epsilon_2 \\
\zeta_3
\end{eqnarray}$$

In particular, I'm asked to give an example where $g$ is surjective but $g\circ f$ is not, and it would seem that if $g$ is surjective, then $g\circ f$ is necessarily surjective. How would I prove this?

---

So, Mr. Thomas Andrews seems to be saying construct something like this:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\cdot \rightarrow \cdot \rightarrow \cdot \\
\cdot \nearrow {\color{red}\cdot} \rightarrow \cdot \\
\cdot \rightarrow \cdot \rightarrow \cdot
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: Hint: Find an $f$ which is not surjective.

Comment: I see, what a mistake.

Comment: The converse is actually  true: If $g\circ f$ is onto, then $g$ is onto.

Comment: In my Thomas-Andrews comment, the red dot isn't hit.

Comment: Well, the middle dot of the right column isn't hit by $g\circ f$ and the red dot isn't hit by $f$...

Comment: Note that if $g\circ f$ is surjective, $g$ must be. For an arbitrary element $\epsilon_r$ there must be an element $\zeta_r$ which maps to it under the composite map. Then $g$ maps $f(\zeta_r) \to\epsilon_r$

Comment: Try taking $g$ as the identity.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a set $S=\{0,1\}$ and study functions $f,g:S\to S$, $f(x) =0$, $g(x)=x$. $g$ is surjective, $f$ is not. $g(f(x))=0$, so $g\circ f$ is not surjective.